How to deal with Google Programmable Search Engine for *specific search* |
I have created a search bar through "Google Programmable Search Engine". Now I want to make the searchbar working like specifically search for a website not the entire web.
I have added some website links on "Site search" but the results are not showing whenever I search. I have also added some keywords related to my search and according to the website links that I have added in "Search site" but these are not working.
